# White Gap On Side Of Page In Mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, slick.js

I have a website with a slick.js carousel in it. I have noticed a white gap on the side of the page when the website is viewed on devices with screens smaller than about 770px.

[image: The white gap is on the right side.]

After some testing I noticed that if I remove slick.js from the website, the white gap disappears.
At first, I thought the content of slides was causing it, but I reduced each slide to just a couple of words and there is still a white gap.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="m-carousel" dir="rtl">
    <div class="slide">Test Slide</div>
    <div class="slide">Test Slide</div>
    <div class="slide">Test Slide</div>
    <div class="slide">Test Slide</div>
</div>
```

And the Javascript (after page load):

```
$('.m-carousel').slick({
    dots: true,
    rtl: true
});
```

The CSS (regarding the slider):

```
// slick slider styling
.slick-dots li button:before {
    font-size: 9px;
}

.slick-dots li.slick-active button:before {
    color: accent;
}
```

On mobile, the page moves from side to side (when it's not suppose to), revealing and hiding that gap. It's really annoying.

I have tried setting `overflow-x: hidden` to the body, but it causes many problems with the navigation and overall scrolling of the website.

Comment: Could you add your css too? Or even build out a codepen or fiddle?

Comment: @NominalAeon I added the CSS styling the slider. I don't think a fiddle will demonstrate the problem well here, but I'll try.

Comment: No that's fine I was just wanting the css, but I was hoping you were using more on your end. You don't have any styles applied to the container you're slicking?

Comment: @NominalAeon `.m-carousel` is in a `.container` (Bootstrap's one), and that's inside a section that I gave a `min-height`, `padding-bottom` and `border-bottom`.

Comment: And you're sure there isn't another page element breaking the viewport width? .container will take up available width but that doesn't necessarily mean it or Slick is causing it.

Comment: @NominalAeon Yeah, as soon as I remove the reference to `slick.min.js` the problem is gone. I also checked and removed the main elements of the page one by one. I found that as long as the slick carousels were there, the gap was there.

Comment: How about dir="ltr", does this only occur in rtl?

Comment: @NominalAeon I tried without the rtl (in both the js and the markup), and the gap is still there.

Comment: .container adds padding to the sides of the element wrapping .m-carousel. Try setting padding: 0 in the inspector.

Comment: @NominalAeon Still, no difference. Thanks for all your support though.

Comment: No problem. Nothing obvious is jumping out at me, but I'll take a look at your issue if you can get me a working example

Comment: @NominalAeon I finally figured it out. Check out my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It took me a lot of time to figure it out but I finally did.
**The problem was the arrows.** It seems like when you put bootstrap and slick.js together, on a screen width below 767px, there are no arrows and there is a white unexplained gap.

To fix the problem, all I had to do was disable the arrows in the javascript:

```
$('.m-carousel').slick({
  arrows: false
});
```

You can see a demo showing the white gap [here](http://jsfiddle.net/z8zbcLzo/3/).

Thanks a lot to NominalAeon for the continuous help and support.

Comment: ugh. So glad you figured it out, so frustrated I didn't think of that.

Thanks for following up!

Comment: @gofilord Thank you for the answer, saved many hours I presume.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is overflow. You might have been able to keep your arrows and change overflow to hidden.